# Appengine Search API search by Date and Time

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-search

I'm wondering how to have a millisecond since epoch datetime field (e.g. 1362960734565) that I can search on easily (e.g. all documents created after 1234560123456), or do I need to implement some method to split up the date or put it in another format, as it won't work as a NUMBER or a DATE.

According to Google's documentation for the search API (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/overview#Describing_Data_with_Documents):

> Document Fields
>
> Each document contains fields that will contain a particular type of content. The content
>   type is identified by a Field builder to set a field's content type as follows:
>
> - TEXT: plain text
> - HTML: HTML formatted text
> - ATOM: a string which is treated as a single token
> - NUMBER: a numeric value (either float or integer) between 2,147,483,647 and -2,147,483,647
> - DATE: a date with no time component
> - GEO_POINT: a locale based on latitude and longitude

Comment: you could store as an ISO 8601 Atom with millisecond component:  "2013-03-13T00:20:45.123Z"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My current solution:

With the timestamp as a DateTime, I store the date in a Date field type, and then I get the milliseconds of the day and store this as a Number.

I then construct the query for the search API using the numeric operators against these two fields, e.g.:

> dayLastUpdated >= 2013-3-13 AND timeLastUpdated > 82884753